# Create binary categorical variables based on contents of a column delimited list

Tags: r, database, data-cleaning, csv, medical

I have a variable in my dataframe called "Cardiac Comorbidity Types" with either NAs or a column delimited list of various cardiac comorbidity types. How can I make a column for each possible comorbidity, and then fill the observations in with 1/0 where 1=indicates the presense of a comorbidity and 0=no comorbidity.

```
dput(head(et1$`Cardiac Comorbidity Types`,20))
c("MI,", NA, "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, Pacemaker,", "Arrhythmia,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, Arrhythmia,", NA, "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, CHF, Pacemaker,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, Arrhythmia,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, CHF, Arrhythmia,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, Pacemaker,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, CHF,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, CHF,", NA, "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, PVD, Pacemaker,", 
"PVD,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA,")
```

Additionally, how could I do this if the data was semicolon delimited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a combination of `unnest` and `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data <- data %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow(data))

data %>% 
  mutate(Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types = str_split(Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types, ", ?")) %>%
  unnest(Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types) %>%
  filter(Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types != "") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "ID", names_from = Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types, values_from = Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types) %>%
  right_join(data, by="ID") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-ID,-Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types), ~ as.integer(!is.na(.x))) %>% select(-ID)
# A tibble: 20 x 8
#      MI   CAD `Previous CABG or PTCA` Pacemaker Arrhythmia   CHF   PVD Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types                   
#   <int> <int>                   <int>     <int>      <int> <int> <int> <fct>                                       
# 1     1     0                       0         0          0     0     0 MI,                                         
# 2     0     0                       0         0          0     0     0 NA                                          
# 3     1     1                       1         1          0     0     0 CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, Pacemaker,  
# 4     0     0                       0         0          1     0     0 Arrhythmia,                                 
# 5     1     1                       1         0          1     0     0 CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, Arrhythmia, 
...
```

**Data**

```
data <- c("MI,", NA, "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, Pacemaker,", "Arrhythmia,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, Arrhythmia,", NA, "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, CHF, Pacemaker,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, Arrhythmia,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, CHF, Arrhythmia,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, Pacemaker,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, CHF,", 
"CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, MI, CHF,", NA, "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA, PVD, Pacemaker,", 
"PVD,", "CAD, Previous CABG or PTCA,")
data <- data.frame(Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types = data)
```

Comment: when I run the code on the whole dataframe it seems that my table header in my console reads at the end: `Atrial fibrillation` `atrial fibrillation` `MI; Arrhythmia; CHF`...is there a way to fix this that you're aware of?

Comment: also how can I add these columns to my original dataframe?

Comment: Awesome that worked for the semi-colon, but I still have `Atrial fibrillation` `atrial fibrillation` at the top, how can I fix the a/A deal? Also, its the same number of rows as my original dataframe, a bit new to all of this, but how would you use cbind or mutate in the context of this code. really appreciate the help

Comment: sorry by at the top I meant as the headers in my console

Comment: basically its confusing Atrial Fibrillation and atrial fibrillation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211105/discussion-between-bdg67-and-ian-campbell).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape` to convert to binary columns.

```
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(et1, "Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types", 
                          type = "character", fill = 0)
```

The default `sep` argument in  `cSplit_e` is `","`, if you have semi-colon delimited data you can mention that explicitly.

```
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(et1, "Cardiac.Comorbidity.Types", sep = ";", 
                          type = "character", fill = 0)
```